# Find the missing digit in a equation

Tags: c++, c++17

Hello I want to find the missing number in the equation for example. 7+x=17. x=10. This is what I want to do I think the problem in my code is that the code doesn't know how to identify which digit is x.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    char x;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    if (a == x)
    {
        cout << c - b;
    }
    if (b == x)
    {
        cout << c - a;
    }
    if (c == x)
    {
        cout << a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Talk to your code, and have it tell you (a) where does `x` ever get a value, and (b), why would comparing a `char` to `int` make sense in this context ?

Comment: This is some... "exotic" indentation you have there

Comment: @WhozCraig I assign x a value and change char to int ? But I saw a YT tutorial saying if you will assign a single letter make it char and a number int so is the yt video wrong or did I do something wrong

Comment: @Borgleader Sorry if it is hard to read stack overflow wouldn't accept it unless I put a lot of indentation .

Comment: @hazey2 You either need a intendation of 4 spaces more than should show up in the code block on each line plus an empty line before the first line of code or alternatively simply surround the whole thing with tripple backticks before the first and after the last line (both on separate lines).

Comment: Let me put this another way, this line of code: `if (a == x)`. : Look at the lines prior and answer this: *what is the value of `x`* ? The only correct answer is: "I have no idea", because neither does your program. It is *indeterminate*.

Comment: @WhozCraig ohhh I get it now and how to do it but wouldn't it be a problem if a and b were the same number? Would there be a way to fix that?

Comment: How do you compare against a missing number? It's missing. I think you need to rethink what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you have a variety of issues.

First, are you literally expecting input to be something like `7+x=10`? If so, your code isn't going to read that.

You need to break this problem down. You need to read the input. And you need to solve it. So put a cout statement after your cin statement, and you'll see you aren't receiving what you think you should receive.

After that, you can move onto part B, which is to solve the simple algebra. Your code for that is ALMOST.